# Creating new Directory with YUI Compressor task MSBuild Event

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, yui, yui-compressor

I am using YUI for minification. It all works fine. I am planning to keep the generated file in a different directory each time. But if i give a path which doesn't not exist , this task is not able to generate the directory. for me the number 79 will keep changing so that everytime its a new path. If the folder already exists then it fines it copies the minified file.

Any idea or help in creating directory if not exists while generating the file.

I integrated the below one with MSBuild as post build event

```
 <JavaScriptCompressorTask
         SourceFiles="@(jsfile_global)"
         DeleteSourceFiles="false"
         OutputFile="minified/79/global-min.js"
         CompressionType="Standard"
         LoggingType="Info"
         LineBreakPosition="-1"         
    />
```

any help or direction will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will create the directory, if not existing:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Number>79</Number>
</PropertyGroup>

<MakeDir Directories="minified/$(Number)/" Condition="!Exists('minified/$(Number)/')" />
<JavaScriptCompressorTask
     SourceFiles="@(jsfile_global)"
     DeleteSourceFiles="false"
     OutputFile="minified/$(Number)/global-min.js"
     CompressionType="Standard"
     LoggingType="Info"
     LineBreakPosition="-1"         
/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much let me try this one

Comment: once again Thanks very much Mike , it works like charm , my problem solved.